# Expected value of colors picked from basket

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I have a basket with 4 balls with different colors.
What is the expected value of distinct colors I can see after picking 4 times from bin. I return the ball back after each try.

I tried computing probabilities of number of colors

$$\mathbb{P}(1) = \binom 41 \times \frac 1{4^4}$$

$$\mathbb{P}(4) = 1 \times \frac 34 \times \frac 24 \times \frac 14$$

But I struggle with computing $\mathbb{P}(2)$ and $\mathbb{P}(3)$.
I was thinking:

$$\mathbb{P}(2) = \binom 42 \times  \frac 1{2^4} - \mathbb{P}(1) = \frac 6{16} - \frac 1{64} = \frac {23}{64}$$
but I was told that I am wrong.

Comment: A useful tutorial on formatting can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thank you, I will try do better next time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of obtaining two colours twice each is
$$\frac{4\times3\times3}{4^4}=\frac{9}{64}$$
(pick the colour which occurs first; pick another place for the same colour; pick the remaining colour).  The probability of obtaining one colour once and another three times is
$$\frac{4\times4\times3}{4^4}=\frac{12}{64}$$
(pick the colour to occur once; place it; pick the other colour).  So
$$P(2)=\frac{21}{64}\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

The probability of seeing the $i$-th color when you have $n$ colors at least once in $k$ draws is $1-(1-1/n)^k$ (the latter term is the probability of not seeing color $i$ in $k$ draws). Then, the average number of colors you see is $E[\mathbb{1}_{\text{color 1 is seen in k draws }} + \mathbb{1}_{\text{color 2 is seen in k draws }} + \ldots + \mathbb{1}_{\text{color n is seen in k draws }}] = n E[\mathbb{1}_{\text{color 1 is seen in k draws }}] = n (1-(1-1/n)^k)$.

Comment: Using linearity of expectation, as done in this answer, very often provides simpler and more elegant calculations than determining the distribution explicitly.